# Scanner is giving me trouble in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I am writing a code to calculate the amount of crates you need depending on the amount of bottles you have.

6 bottles equal 1 crate.

For example, if you'd input 4 bottles, the output would be 1 crate.
If you'd input 9 bottles, you'd get 2 crates etc..

Now I am facing some trouble trying to give the user a choice if they want to calculate again or not.
Heres my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean again = true;
    boolean loop = true;

    while (again) {
      System.out.println("CRATE CALCULATION");
      System.out.println("==================");
      System.out.println("Number of bottles?: ");

      int bottles;
      if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        bottles = scanner.nextInt();
        if (bottles <= 0) {
          System.out.println("You dont need any crates!");
        } else {
          int crates = (bottles + 5) / 6;
          System.out.println("You need " + crates + " crates!");
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to calculate again? (y/n)");
        String choice = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.nextLine();

        switch (choice) {
        case "y":
          again = true;
          break;
        case "n":
          again = false;
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid choice. Lets try again.");
          again = true;
          break;
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("You need to tell us the amount of bottles you have in numbers.");
        scanner.next();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that whenever i enter "y" to calculate again, instead of running the "y" case, it runs the default one. I did research, even talked to ChatGPT but nothing works. Im thinking the problem here lies within scanner, but thats just me.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a standard sanity-debugging step: print the content of `choice` before you start switching, and print it between some brackets, to see what's actually in it. And those brackets are important, because you want to see whether there are any special whitespace characters or not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I did it, and it didnt print out anything. Its a blank line.
Im guessing the scanner didnt take the input, but why?

Comment: `scanner.nextInt()` won't consume the new line which is in the buffer, so your next call to `String choice = scanner.nextLine();` will return an empty `String`.  Instead of calling `scanner.nextLine();` after it (which you seem to have identified as a symptom of the problem), call `scanner.nextLine();` before `String choice = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're a life saver man. It works now! Thanks a lot. But could you explain again, why it didnt work and why it works now? I dont seem to understand, so maybe try explaining it like you would explain it to a 5 year old? 

Comment: @Prime I only understand it from an observational point of view, but when you time something into the console, the `Scanner` will consume all the text, including the new line character (which is injected when you press enter). `nextInt` will only remove the characters from the buffer which form a valid `int` value, the new line character will remain.  So the next call to `nextLine` will return an empty `String`, because there's no other characters proceeding the new line character, but will "wait" for input at the second `nextLine`, as no new data exists yet

Comment: @MadProgrammer Got it, Thanks! Have a great rest of the week.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.